# Uniform continuity of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove $e^x$ is uniformly continuous on interval $(0,1)$ ? I have tried it with basic definition but I am not able to prove.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mean value theorem to show that 
$$\forall x,y\in [0,1],\, |e^x-e^y|\leq e|x-y|$$

Combine this with the definition of uniform continuity and you'll the find the right modulus of continuity.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y \in (0,1)$, From Lagrange's MVT, there's a $c\in (x,y)$ such that:
$$\frac{e^x - e^y}{x-y} = e^c$$

Since the exponent function is monotonically increasing:

$$\frac{e^x - e^y}{x-y} = e^c \le e^1$$

Therefore, the function is $e$-Lipchitz on $(0,1)$ which implies uniform continuity.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use the inequality 
$$
\lvert e^h-1\rvert \le e\lvert h\rvert,\qquad \forall |h|\le 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are intervals and $A \subset B$ and a function $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $B$, then it is also uniformly continous in $A$.

$e^x$ is a continuous function, so it's uniformly continuos on the compact interval $[0,1]$ (Heince Cantor theorem); therefore it's uniformly continous in $(0,1)$